# MongoDB date with time as part of a compound index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Hello I have objects like this one in the db:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d9fc68bb9dcdcc9f73e6b7"), "ApplicationId" : 9, "CreatedDateUtc" : ISODate("2016-01-01T21:26:57.116Z"), "Message" : "yolo", "EventType" : 4 }`

And I will search by the `ApplicationId` and the `CreatedDateUtc` (optionally `EventType`) fields so I made a composite index (I kept the defult index on id field intact):

```
{
     "v" : 1,
     "key" : {
             "ApplicationId" : 1,
             "CreatedDateUtc" : -1
     },
     "name" : "ApplicationId_1_CreatedDateUtc_-1",
     "ns" : "test.testLogs"
}
```

Is that a good idea to use a field which is unique almost every time (the date) as part of the index? If I get the whole index idea, then this approach will bloat the index making it harder to find stuff fast. Am I correct?
With 770k entries I have ~19MB index. I have no idea is it large or not, but it *seems* big.

```
> db.testLogs.count()
770999
> db.testLogs.totalIndexSize()
18952192
```

I was thinking about making a field unique for each hour (maybe the date with minutes and the small stuff floor'ed) and use it for indexing. Any better ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this index?

Comment: Increase the speed of searching by ApplicationId and the date.

Comment: Well, in modern servers 19MB is nothing. It's not only giving you a unique value but provide you over valuable information such as date time, machine id and so. much like audit trail. However, you can provide your own Id value instead of default ObjectId but in this case, you are responsible to make sure it's unique.

Comment: I am not trying to create a unique identifier, I am trying to create an index which will increase the speed of very certain search queries based on two fields I mentioned.

Comment: @user1713059 That's the right index for that sort of query. The more unique the data in the index is, the better.